# Computer accessible via IP and shown in NET VIEW, doesn't automatically appear in Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, samba, file-sharing, netbios

The LAN with the problem has about 5 Win 8.1 PCs and a unix file server. The file server also acts as browser master via samba. File sharing works fine, each machine can see the others - except one (call it \\JANE, with IP = 192.168.1.5).

\\JANE isn't seen by any machine (including itself) in Windows explorer -> Networks. I can access it using \\JANE or \\192.168.1.5 and then it is listed in Explorer, but open a new explorer window and it's missing again. I can also remote desktop to it using \\JANE, and ping it. It appears in the other computers when I enter `net view` in cmd.exe. But I can't seem to fix the inconsistency that all other machines appear in Explorer and this one doesn't.

It's surely an issue with that machine (and not with the file server or another machine) because the results are the same for all LAN machines, including \\JANE itself. It's also not a firewall or connectivity issue since I can reach \\JANE via its name or IP, it shows up under `net view` on all machines, and the issue affects \\JANE seeing itself, identically as it affects other machines.

Things I've tried:

\\JANE has file sharing running. It has standard NIC config, including the 2 services needed for file discovery. Its registry settings for NetBT seem the same as the other machines. I've flushed the ARP cache. I've checked no firewall blocking it and same workgroup (="WORKGROUP"). I've killed A/V. Nothing has made any difference that I can figure out.

At my wits end what else it could be and where else to look, at this point.

Comment: Is it configured on the same workgroup in the system properties?

Comment: yes - question updated noting it